# Node.js: Display image in website as REST API call result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got an image tag on my website to display a jpg image like such:

```
<img src="/loadthumbnail/alphanumericimageID" width="200" height="130">
```

This call triggers a REST API call on my server to another external webservice, eventually delivering the image I want to be displayed. After saving the image on my server, I send it back to the client (Browser):

```
return ImageGrabberClass.grabImagefromAnotherServer(imageID).bind(this)
    .then(function(localPathtoImage){
        res.sendfile(localPathtoImage);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        //Foo
    });
```

After a couple of seconds, the image is indeed shown on the webpage but seems to be distorted somehow (stretched or squeezed, respectively). I checked on three different browsers - same result everywhere, every time. The saved image file on my webserver is perfectly fine, right dimensions and no distortion whatsoever.
What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Putting width and height on your img tag will resize your image (hence stretching, etc if you are not respecting the image's ration)

Comment: Yes but the dimension is in fact identical - always 200x130 so there shouldn't be any stretching...

Comment: maybe you have some css rules which define the size of your picture?

Comment: I guess we have a winner. There was indeed some css action going that I missed unfortunately. Thanks again =)